# binary search tree recursion without return statement on the function calls

Tags: java

I am learning binary search tree using recursion and I made the below mistake of not adding return in line X and Y as commented out below.

What difference does not having the return statement mean on the stack of the function call? Apologies if the query is very basic but I would like to clarify it here.

I thought not having the return statement on the function call will still work as it will find a match and return the value if it exists in the array.

Sample values passed to the function

```
   int found = searchRecursive(new int[]{0, 1, 21, 33, 45, 45, 61, 71, 72, 73},21);

        System.out.println(found);
```

**Code**

```
 private static int searchRecursive(int array[], int target) {
        int low = 0;
        int high = array.length -1;
        return binarySearch(array, low, high, target);
    }

   private static int binarySearch(int array[], int low, int high, int target){
        int mid = (low+high)/2;
        if(array[mid] == target){
            return mid;
        }
        else if(array[mid]>target) {
            return binarySearch(array, low, mid - 1, target); //line X
        } else {
            return binarySearch(array, mid+1, high, target);  //line Y
        }
    }
```

So I had it as below and it found the value but ended up finally returning as -1 instead of 21

```
private static int binarySearch(int array[], int low, int high, int target){
        int mid = (low+high)/2;
        if(array[mid] == target){
            return mid;
        }
        else if(array[mid]>target) {
            binarySearch(array, low, mid - 1, target); //line X
        } else {
            binarySearch(array, mid+1, high, target);  //line Y
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: Just think about what happens if you're missing those intermediate returns in recursive calls: the last call might return the found index but how would the second to last call know it should return anything if that statement was missing?

Comment: "I had it as below and it found the value but ended up finally returning as -1 instead of 21" - that cannot be true as the code snipped you posted there wouldn't compile. If there's a return value defined the method _always_ will have to return something. There's also no indication of why it would return -1 so that seems to be missing too.

Comment: Apart from what @Thomas wrote: a recursive method call is no different from any other method call. Think of it as if you were calling a different method. What does binarySearch then do? It just calls another method then continues its work.

Comment: @Thomas - I had a return -1 in the end, sorry I missed that. I am adding it to the original thread.

Comment: @Thomas and Mike thanks for the explanation, Mike's additional point abovee makes it clearer for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you do not detect failure to find an element. In fact `low` and `high` may run out of bounds by 1.

```
private static int binarySearch(int array[], int low, int high, int target) {
    if (low > high) {
        return -1;
    }
    int mid = (low+high)/2;
    if (array[mid] == target) {
        return mid;
    } else if (target < array[mid]) {
        return binarySearch(array, low, mid - 1, target); //line X
    } else {
        return binarySearch(array, mid + 1, high, target);  //line Y
    }
}
```

If one `return` is dropped, but the compiler can find a final `return`, the result is that of a temporary result.

You could also move the bounds more clearly:

```
private static int binarySearch(int array[], int low, int high, int target) {
    if (low > high) {
        return -1;
    }
    int mid = (low+high)/2;
    if (array[mid] == target) {
        return mid;
    }
    if (target < array[mid]) {
        high = mid - 1;
    } else {
        low = mid + 1;
    }
    return binarySearch(array, low, high, target);
}
```

And hence the iterative (non-recursive) version is:

```
private static int binarySearch(int array[], int low, int high, int target) {
    while (low <= high) {
        int mid = (low+high)/2;
        if (array[mid] == target) {
            return mid;
        }
        if (target < array[mid]) {
            high = mid - 1;
        } else {
            low = mid + 1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```